# No speed up with python multiprocessing

Tags: python, performance, numpy, multiprocessing, python-xarray

I am trying to speed up the calculation of bootstrap estimates using python `'mp``. However I am not seeing any speed up.
The data I am trying to apply bootstrapping to are gridded (time,lat,lon) and read from netcdf using xarray.

Here is what I have done.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import xarray as xr

def boot_mean(idata):
    return(idata.mean(dim='boot_ax'))

def process_boot(nsample,bfun,idata):
    ind_boot        =  np.random.choice(len(idata['boot_ax']),nsample)
    return(bfun(idata.isel(boot_ax=ind_boot)))


#geo bootstrap                                                                                                                                                                                
def geo_bootstrap(idata_raw,bfun,nsample=0,nboot=1000,scoord='time',\
                  np=1):

    idata = idata_raw.rename({scoord:'boot_ax'})


    if nsample==0:
        nsample=len(idata['boot_ax'])
    if np==1:
        C  = xr.concat([process_boot(nsample,bfun,idata) \ 
                        for x in range(nboot)],dim='boot')
    else:
        pool    = mp.Pool(processes=np)
        results = [pool.apply_async(process_boot,args=(nsample,bfun,idata))   for x in range(nboot)]

        C = xr.concat([p.get() for p in results],dim='boot')
        pool.close()

    return(C)
```

With 1 cpu, the code takes ~7s

```
%%time
O = geo_bootstrap(INPUT,boot_mean,nboot=20)
CPU times: user 6.79 s, sys: 268 ms, total: 7.06 s
Wall time: 7.1 s
```

With 4 cpus, the code takes longer, which I cannot quite understand

```
%%time
O = geo_bootstrap(INPUT,boot_mean,nboot=20,np=4)

CPU times: user 2.14 s, sys: 4.34 s, total: 6.49 s
Wall time: 8.44 s
```

The machine I am running on has plenty of memory. It's my first attempt with `mp` and I am not sure what is the bottleneck.
INPUT is an xarray dataset

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:           (bnds: 2, time: 15, xh: 720, yh: 576)
Coordinates:
  * time              (time) object 1990-07-02 12:00:00 ... 1994-07-02 12:00:00
  * xh                (xh) float64 -299.8 -299.2 -298.8 ... 58.75 59.25 59.75
  * yh                (yh) float64 -77.91 -77.72 -77.54 ... 89.47 89.68 89.89
    x                 (yh, xh) float64 -299.8 -299.2 -298.8 ... 59.99 59.99 60.0
    y                 (yh, xh) float64 -77.91 -77.91 -77.91 ... 65.18 64.97
Dimensions without coordinates: bnds
Data variables:
    time_bnds         (time, bnds) object 1990-01-01 00:00:00 ... 1995-01-01 00:00:00
    dep_n             (time, yh, xh) float32 nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
    tot_fsn           (time, yh, xh) float32 nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
    epc100            (time, yh, xh) float32 nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
    nh4_stf           (time, yh, xh) float32 nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
    wc_vert_int_nfix  (time, yh, xh) float32 nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
    no3os             (time, yh, xh) float32 nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
```

**Additional information**

I think the issue may be that the array is passed to each subprocess.
If I redefine the functions as follows:

```
def process_boot(nsample):
    ind_boot        =  np.random.choice(len(INPUT['time']),nsample)
    return(INPUT.isel(time=ind_boot).mean(dim='time'))


#geo bootstrap                                                                                                                                                                                
def geo_bootstrap(idata_raw,bfun,nsample=0,nboot=1000,scoord='time',\
                  np=1):
    '''bootstrap estimates of time,lat,lon dataset                                                                                                                                                  
    '''


    idata = idata_raw.rename({scoord:'boot_ax'})


    if nsample==0:
        nsample=len(idata['boot_ax'])
    if np==1:
        C  = xr.concat([process_boot(nsample) for x in range(nboot)],dim='boot')
    else:
        pool    = mp.Pool(processes=np)
        results = [pool.apply_async(process_boot,args=(nsample,))   for x in range(nboot)]

        C = xr.concat([p.get() for p in results],dim='time')
        pool.close()

    return(C)
```

I get a nice speed up

```
%%time
O = geo_bootstrap(historical_diff_ts,boot_mean,nboot=20,np=5)
CPU times: user 350 ms, sys: 585 ms, total: 935 ms
Wall time: 2.41 s
```

But then the code is not as modular as I would like.

Comment: Multiprocessing has overhead.  New Python processes have to start and data has to be passed via interprocess mechanisms.  That can easily overwhelm a task that takes only 7 seconds.

Comment: @Fxipzap : Can you pickle the xarray and share it here? I'll try analyzing the issue

Comment: Thanks to both of you.
I have uploaded the file here: ftp://ftp.gfdl.noaa.gov/pub/Fabien.Paulot/for_stack_overflow/merge.nc